# ASP.NET Page elements disappear after click on button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 pages, the first (Index) is a form with 2 TextForm and the 2 informations are sent by POST method.
In the second page (WebForm), after clicking the button to update the time, the other 2 items (FirstName and LastName) disappears, I don't understand why?
How should I do to "keep" the 2 items too ?

These are all the pages:

index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="HelloWorlds.Index" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="firstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox ID="secondName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="GO!" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm.aspx" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="HelloWorlds.WebForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="item1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" Text="Click Here!" OnClick="b1_Click"></asp:Button>
            <br /> <br />
            <asp:Label ID="labelFirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
           <asp:Label ID="labelLastName" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HelloWorlds
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

WebForm.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HelloWorlds
{
    public partial class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime actualDate = DateTime.Now;
            item1.Text = actualDate.ToString();
            string firstName = Request.Form["firstName"];
            string lastName = Request.Form["secondName"];
            if (firstName == "FirstName" && lastName == "SecondName") {
            labelFirstName.Text = "Not Valid";
            labelLastName.Text = "Not Valid";
        }
            else { 
           labelFirstName.Text = firstName;
            labelLastName.Text = lastName;
            }
        }

        protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime actualDate = DateTime.Now;
            item1.Text = actualDate.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to understand that web firms are not the same as Windows form. Web forms are state less so when you click the button entire page loads again which executes page_load again. So next pay load will not have values of `Request.Form["firstName"]` and other. That's why you see the values disappearing. You need to put the code of page_load inside `if(!IsPostBack)` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a Cross Page Postback: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

You want something similar to:

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    TextBox srcFirstName= 
        (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("firstName");
    if (srcFirstName!= null)
    {
        firstName = srcLastName.Text;
    }

    TextBox srcLastName= 
        (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("lastName");
    if (srcLastName!= null)
    {
        lastName = srcLastName.Text;
    }
}
```

**Note** this is a rough and untested example but should get you moving in the right direction.